# Testing for non-ascii characters copied from webpages

Tags: testing, non-ascii-characters

So, I'm finding lots of things about removing non-ascii characters, but not really adding them.

Basically, I have a text field that a user can type in, and then that string gets processed, stored, and presented under certain contexts. I expect the user to sometimes just copy and paste text from other webpages, and I want to make sure that nothing the user enters in that field will break anything. (I know this is a potential problem because a user coping and pasting a ' that was not actually an ascii ' already broke things once)

This is NOT about removing non-ascii characters! I want a good list/file of possible problem characters I can copy and paste to verify that they get processed correctly. Or at the very least, a good way to find these potential copy paste 'impostor' characters.

Comment: See the Unicode [name list](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) or the [database (text file)](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Tom Blodget. After shifting through and minimizing text, the following is a list of all UTF-8 characters that can be copied and pasted. (here is [UTF-16](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm) and [UFT-32](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-32/list.htm) lists. I don't have time to copy these lists to a text file. If those links are broken, use [Google for UFT-16 table](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+all+utf8+characters&oq=list+of+all+utf8+characters&aqs=chrome..69i57.14199j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=utf-16+table) and [Google for UTF-32 table](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+all+utf8+characters&oq=list+of+all+utf8+characters&aqs=chrome..69i57.14199j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=utf-32+table))

!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿĂăĄąĆćČčĎďĐđĘęĚěĹĺĽľŁłŃńŇňŐőŒœŔŕŘřŚśŞşŠšŢţŤťŮůŰűŸŹźŻżŽžƒˆˇ˘˙˛˜˝–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›€™